# Extracting columns with constant numbers in R data.frames

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

In data.frame `DATA`, I have some columns that are constant numbers across the unique rows of the first column called `study.name`. For example, columns `ESL` and `prof` are **constant** for all rows of `Shin.Ellis` and **constant** for all rows of `Trus.Hsu` and so on. Including `Shin.Ellis` and `Trus.Hsu`, there are **8** unique `study.name` rows.

BUT after my `split.default()` call below, how can I obtain only one data-point for all rows under a unique `study.name` (e.g., one for `Shin.Ellis`, one for `Trus.Hsu` etc.) for such constant variables? (i.e., **8** rows overall)

For example, after my `split.default()`, all variables named `ESL` show only have `8` rows each for a unique `study.name`.

**My desired output** for **ONLY** `ESL` and `prof` is shown further below.

***NOTE***: This is toy data. We first should find constant variables. A functional answer is highly appreciated.

```
DATA <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr.csv", h = T)[-(2:3)]
DATA <- setNames(DATA, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(DATA)))

tbl <- table(names(DATA))
nm2 <- names(which(tbl==max(tbl)))

L <- split.default(DATA[names(DATA) %in% nm2], names(DATA)[names(DATA) %in% nm2])


## FIRST 8 ROWS of `DATA`:

#    study.name ESL prof scope type   ESL   prof   scope   type
# 1  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
# 2  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
# 3  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    2     1      2       1      1
# 4  Shin.Ellis   1    2     1    2     1      2       1      1
# 5  Shin.Ellis   1    2    NA   NA     1      2      NA     NA
# 6  Shin.Ellis   1    2    NA   NA     1      2      NA     NA
# 7    Trus.Hsu   2    2     2    1     2      2       1      1
# 8    Trus.Hsu   2    2    NA   NA     2      2      NA     NA
# .     ...       .    .     .    .     .      .       .      . # `DATA` has 54 rows overall
```

## Desired output for `ESL` and `prof` after `split.default()` call:

```
# $ESL            ## 8 unique rows for 8 unique `study.name`
#    ESL ESL.1
# 1    1     1
# 7    2     2
# 9    1     1
# 17   1     1
# 23   1     1
# 35   1     1
# 37   2     2
# 49   2     2


# $prof           ## 8 unique rows for 8 unique `study.name`
#    prof prof.1
# 1     2      2
# 7     2      2
# 9     3      3
# 17    2      2
# 23    2      2
# 35    2      2
# 37   NA     NA
# 49    2      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first find constant columns and then use `lapply` to loop over them and select only their first row in each `study.name`.

```
is_constant <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1L 
cols <- names(Filter(all, aggregate(.~study.name, DATA, is_constant)[-1]))

L[cols] <- lapply(L[cols], function(x) 
                      x[ave(x[[1]], DATA$study.name, FUN = seq_along) == 1, ])
L

#$ESL
#   ESL ESL.1
#1    1     1
#7    2     2
#9    1     1
#17   1     1
#23   1     1
#35   1     1
#37   2     2
#49   2     2

#$prof
#   prof prof.1
#1     2      2
#7     2      2
#9     3      3
#17    2      2
#23    2      2
#35    2      2
#37   NA     NA
#49    2      2
#.....
```

Comment: @rnorouzian I think in that case, you can change inside function to `x[ave(seq_along(x[[1]]), DATA$study.name, FUN = seq_along) == 1, ])`

Comment: Hi Ronak, did @rnorouzian's question make sense to you or he's missing something? -- Thank you.

Comment: Hi...if you still have additional questions please ask a new question.

Comment: Dear Ronak could you see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791480/find-the-name-of-constant-columns-in-an-r-data-frame) and the problem?

Comment: I again, found an error in your solution (the one you edited in comment above). To see the problem, suppose `DATA` was: `a <- data.frame(study.name = c(1,1,2,3), mod.s=c(3,3,1,2), mod.g=c(1,1,3,1));
b <- data.frame(study.name = c(1,1,2,3), mod.s=c(3,3,2,2), mod.g=c(1,2,3,2));
DATA <- cbind(a,b)`, also `L` was : `L <- split(DATA, DATA$study.name)`. Now if you run your code starting with `cols` should not return anything because `"mod.s"` and `"mod.g"` are not constant in `DATA`, but it wrongly returns `"mod.s"` and  `"mod.g"`? Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

We can create the expected output with `aggregate`

```
is_constant <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1L 
nm1 <-  names(which(!colSums(!aggregate(.~ study.name, DATA, is_constant)[-1])))
L[nm1] <- lapply(L[nm1], function(x) aggregate(x, 
   list(factor(DATA$study.name, levels = unique(DATA$study.name))), 
          FUN = head, 1)[-1])
L
#$ESL
#  ESL ESL.1
#1   1     1
#2   2     2
#3   1     1
#4   1     1
#5   1     1
#6   1     1
#7   2     2
#8   2     2

#$prof
#  prof prof.1
#1    2      2
#2    2      2
#3    3      3
#4    2      2
#5    2      2
#6    2      2
#7   NA     NA
#8    2      2

#$scope
#...
```

Comment: A follow-up, suppose `DATA` was the following in my original post: `DATA <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/c.csv")`. Based on what I asked in my question, your code: `nm1` should return 3 names: `"setting" "prof"   "random"` BUT, it incorrectly also returns `"error"`. However, `"error"` is not a constant over all `study.name`s. For example, look at `study.name == "Sun"`, you see in one row `"error"` is `2` & in another row `"error"` is `0`, but why `"error"` is returned as a constant variable?

Comment: @rnorouzian Can you post as a new question.  Thanks