# Find the names of constant columns in an R data.frame

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

This is a follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314023/extracting-columns-with-constant-numbers-in-r-data-frames). In data.frame `DATA`, I have some columns that are constant numbers across the unique rows of the first column called `study.name`. For example, columns `setting`, `prof` and `random` are **constant** for all rows of `Shin.Ellis` and **constant** for all rows of `Trus.Hsu` and so on. Including `Shin.Ellis` and `Trus.Hsu`, there are **10** unique `study.name` rows.

I wonder how to find the names of such constant columns?

A solution was provided below (see `NAMES`) but I wonder why `"error"` which is not constant throughout is outputted from `NAMES`?

```
DATA <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/cc.csv")
DATA <- setNames(DATA, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(DATA)))

is_constant <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1L 

(NAMES <- names(Filter(all, aggregate(.~study.name, DATA, is_constant)[-1])) )

# > [1] "setting" "prof"   "error"   "random"   ## "error" is NOT a constant variable 
                                                ## BUT why it is outputted here!

# Desired output: 
# [1] "setting" "prof" "random"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass `na.action` to take care of the `NA` elements, otherwise, it would completely remove the whole row

```
names(Filter(all, aggregate(.~study.name, DATA, is_constant, 
            na.action = na.pass)[-1]))
#[1] "setting" "prof"    "random"
```

Comment: A quick follow-up. Suppose `DATA` was: `a <- data.frame(study.name = c(1,1,2,3), mod.s=c(3,3,1,2), mod.g=c(1,1,3,1));
b <- data.frame(study.name = c(1,1,2,3), mod.s=c(3,3,2,2), mod.g=c(1,2,3,2));
DATA <- cbind(a,b)`. Now if you run your code, it should not return anything because `"mod.s"` and `"mod.g"` are not constant in `DATA`, but it wrongly returns `"mod.s"` and  `"mod.g"`? Can you help?

Comment: @rnorouzian in your previous dataset, there is only a single `study.name` column

Comment: @rnorouzian can you please check your data.  It is giving the output exactly as it was supposed to give because the is_constant by group is returning TRUE.  There are duplicate column names 'mod.s' and 'mod.'g is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: @rnorouzian Perhaps you meant `DATA <- rbind(a, b)` and then you get `names(Filter(all, aggregate(.~study.name, DATA, is_constant, 
            na.action = na.pass)[-1]))#
character(0)`

Comment: Sorry fell asleep suddenly! No `DATA <- cbind(a,b)`  is correct. If you remember this form of `DATA` is related to my question [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314023/extracting-columns-with-constant-numbers-in-r-data-frames)? You can skip the additional column for `"study.name"`.

Comment: @rnorouzian if it is `cbind`, then the code is correct because it is looking for unique values by group and it is getting TRUE and that is the reason you are getting mod.s, mod.g